# UIWebView Woes - Error 101

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

UIWebView won't load (Error 101) the following URL:
http://afrikaans.news24.com/Sci-tech/Nuus/Rwanda-gaan-Suid-Afrikaanse-wild-invoer-20111116

I have tried percentescapes to no avail. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Set the URL to go to for your UIWebView
NSString *webAddressString = @"http://afrikaans.news24.com/Sci-tech/Nuus/Rwanda-gaan-Suid-Afrikaanse-wild-invoer-20111116";
NSLog(@"show webAddressString: %@", webAddressString);

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *weburl = [NSURL URLWithString:webAddressString];
[webAddressString release];
//URL Requst Object 
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:weburl];

//load the URL into the web view.
[aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Error 101 is `The operation couldn’t be completed.`, which is led by either domain not found , network problem or even object allocation ( as searched from Google ) .

Comment: got it to work like this, but unfortunately I cant hard code the urls

Comment: found problem, string contained invisible new line chars

Comment: +1 omg, that was my problem too!!  thought I was going crazy. Might be nice to update your question to reflect the fix. I'd + the question if you did. (almost skipped this question with a +0)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
NSString *unencodedURLString = @"http://afrikaans.news24.com/Sci-tech/Nuus/Rwanda-gaan-Suid-Afrikaanse-wild-invoer-20111116";
NSString *encodedURLString = [unencodedURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *weburl = [NSURL encodedURLString];
//URL Requst Object 
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:weburl];

//load the URL into the web view.
[aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```